# MySQL SELECT Query Question

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with two columns: a and b.
There are 20 entries in that table

For 10 entries, a = 3. For the other 10 entries, a = 4.

I want to select rows such that b = 0, but I only want one from the group where a = 3, and one from the group a = 4.

The base query would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE b = 0 AND rest_of_query
```

What should rest_of_query be?

Comment: Do u want the first matching it or a random one ?

Comment: Can you use more descriptive column names for your examples? If you only want one of the a = 3 and a = 4s, what criteria do you want to use to determine which one to return. Does it matter which one?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group seems to cover the same idea

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you only need the first from both the group.
You can do this by:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE b=0 AND a=3 LIMIT 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE b=0 AND a=4 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Oh yea i forgot to remove them. Sorry :d

Answer (score 0):

Given that you haven't specified any particular criteria for the additional columns (if any), the following query will provide what you want.  The specific rows selected will probably be non-deterministic.

```
select * from `table_name` where b=0 group by a;
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand You Only have 2 columns, and are defining what one of them shoudld be and then you want only distinct entries for the other column.

This can be done by GROUP BY as

```
SELECT a, b FROM table_name WHERE b = 0 GROUP BY a;
```

Answer (score 0):

UNION query should be like this

```
(SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE b=0 AND a=3 LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM `table_name` WHERE b=0 AND a=4 LIMIT 1);
```